# Frequency table for multiselect survey question across several columns

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, frequency

I want to do a fairly common analysis of survey questions in R, but am stuck in the middle.

Imagine a survey where you are asked to answer which brands do you associate with certain features (e.g. "brands" could be PlayStation, XBox..., and features could be "speed", "graphics"... where each brand can be checked on several features aka mulit-select). E.g. sth. like this here: https://www.harvestyourdata.com/fileadmin/images/question-type-screenshots/Grid-multi-select.jpg

You often refer to these questions as multi-select grid or matrix questions.

Anyway, from a data perspective, this kind of data is usually stored in wide format where each row*column combination is one variable, which is 0/1 coded (0 if the survey participant doesn't check the box, 1 otherwise).

Assuming we have 5 brands and 10 items, we would have 50 variables in total, ideally following a nice, structured naming scheme, e.g. item1_column1, item2_column1, item3_column1, [...], item1_column2 and so on.

Now, I want to analyze (frequency table) all of these variables in one iteration. I've already found the *cross.multi.table* function in the *questionr* package. However, it only allows to analyze all items based on on single factor. What I need instead is to allow for several columns at the same time.

Any ideas? MIght be I'm missing a function from another package or this can easily be done with tidyverse or even with the cross.multi.table function?

Using this data as test input:

```
dat = data.frame(item1_column1 = c(0,1,1,1),
                 item2_column1 = c(1,1,1,0),
                 item3_column1 = c(0,0,1,1),
                 item1_column2 = c(1,1,1,0),
                 item2_column2 = c(0,1,1,1),
                 item3_column2 = c(1,0,1,1),
                 item1_column3 = c(0,1,1,0),
                 item2_column3 = c(1,1,1,1),
                 item3_column3 = c(0,0,1,0))
```

I'd expect this output:

```
         column1    column2    column3
item1    3          3          2
item2    3          3          4
item3    2          3          1
```

or ideally as proportions/percentages:

```
         column1    column2    column3
item1    75%        75%        50%
item2    75%        75%        100%
item3    50%        75%        25%
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way could be to get data into long format using `gather`, `separate` columns based on `_`, `group_by` `item` and `column` and calculate the ratio of `value` column and `spread` the data to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
  gather(key, value) %>%
  separate(key, into = c("item", "column"), sep = "_") %>%
  group_by(item, column) %>%
  summarise(prop = mean(value) * 100) %>%
  spread(column, prop)

#  item  column1 column2 column3
#  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 item1      75      75      50
#2 item2      75      75     100
#3 item3      50      75      25
```

A bit shorter (Thanks to @M-M)

```
dat %>%
  summarise_all(~mean(.) * 100) %>%
  gather(key, value) %>%
  separate(key, into = c("item", "column"), sep = "_") %>%
  spread(column, value)
```

Comment: If you summarise before gather, you don't need to group by

Comment: Thanks, looks elegant and I can follow the syntax/understand it (as opposed to the data.table and xtabs solution, which are still correct, though).

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in `base R`, by creating a two column data.frame with the column names replicated, `cbind` with the `unlist`ed values, and use `xtabs` to get the `sum` while pivoting to 'wide' format

```
out <- xtabs(val ~ ., cbind(read.table(text = names(dat)[col(dat)],
    sep="_", header = FALSE), val = unlist(dat, use.names = FALSE)))

out
#    V2
#V1      column1 column2 column3
#  item1       3       3       2
#  item2       3       3       4
#  item3       2       3       1
```

Or as @GKi mentioned (a compact version would be) to split the column names by `_`, create a `data.frame` with that along with `colSums` (or `colMeans` - for percentage) and use `xtabs` for pivoting

```
xtabs(n ~ ., data.frame(do.call("rbind", 
              strsplit(colnames(dat), "_")), n=colSums(dat)))
```

---

Or to get the percentage

```
xtabs(val ~ ., aggregate(val ~ ., cbind(read.table(text = names(dat)[col(dat)],
   sep="_", header = FALSE), val = unlist(dat, use.names = FALSE)), mean)) * 100
#     V2
#V1      column1 column2 column3
#  item1      75      75      50
#  item2      75      75     100
#  item3      50      75      25
```

---

Or inspired from @GKi, using `enframe`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
enframe(colSums(dat)) %>% 
   separate(name, into = c('name1', 'name2')) %>% 
   spread(name2, value)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  name1 column1 column2 column3
#  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 item1       3       3       2
#2 item2       3       3       4
#3 item3       2       3       1
```

To get the percentage, just change the first line of code to

```
enframe(100 *colMeans(dat))
```

Comment: or: `xtabs(n ~ ., data.frame(do.call("rbind", strsplit(colnames(dat), "_")), n=colSums(dat)))`. `xtabs` is great! and I was missing until your post.

Comment: @GKi I think it should go as a separate post (can remove from my post if you post as a solution).  i like the way you made it compact

Comment: It's following exact your way, only using different functions. And you have been faster!

Answer (score 1):

What I do here, by using `data.table` package, is summarizing each column, converting data to long format, breaking a column to two (`item` and `column`), and finally converting to wide format. Look below;

```r
library(data.table)

dcast(setDT(melt(setDT(dat)[,100*colMeans(.SD),]),keep.rownames = T)[,
             c("item", "column") := tstrsplit(rn, "_", fixed=TRUE)],
                item ~ column, value.var = "value")

#>     item column1 column2 column3
#> 1: item1      75      75      50
#> 2: item2      75      75     100
#> 3: item3      50      75      25
```