# show unique values for each column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, purrr

I am trying to create a data-frame of the column type and unique variables for each column.

I am able to get column type in the desired data-frame format using `map(df, class) %>% bind_rows() %>% gather(key = col_name, value = col_class)`, but unable to get the unique variables to become a data-frame instead of a list.

Below is a small data-frame and code that gets the unique variables in a list, but not a data frame. Ideally, I could do this in one (map) function, but if I have to join them, it would not be a big deal.

```r
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,2,3,2), v2 = c("a","a","b","b"))

library(tidyverse)

map(df, class) %>% bind_rows() %>% gather(key = col_name, value = col_class)

map(df, unique)
```

When I try to use the same method on the `map(df, unique)` as on the `map(df, class)` I get the following error: `Error: Argument 2 must be length 3, not 2` which is expected, but I am not sure how to get around it.

Comment: what's your desired output?

Comment: Also, instead of `bind_rows %>% spread(...)` do this ```map(df, class) %>% enframe() %>% unnest()```

Comment: @M-M I have not heard of `enframe()` and `unnest()`. I am working on understanding the documentation, but what is the benefit of that over `bind_rows() %>% gather()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number of unique values are different in those two columns. You need to reduce them to a single element.

```
df2 <- map(df, ~str_c(unique(.x),collapse = ",")) %>% 
    bind_rows() %>% 
    gather(key = col_name, value = col_unique)
```

```
> df2
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  col_name col_class
  <chr>    <chr>    
1 v1       1,2,3    
2 v2       a,b
```

Answer (score 4):

We could use `map_df` and get the `class` and `unique` values from each column into one `tibble`. Since every column would have variables of different type, we need to bring them in one common class to bind the data together in one dataframe.

```
purrr::map_df(df,~tibble::tibble(class = class(.), value = as.character(unique(.))))

#  class  value
#  <chr>  <chr>
#1 numeric 1    
#2 numeric 2    
#3 numeric 3    
#4 factor  a    
#5 factor  b
```

Or if you want to have only one value for every column, we could do

```
map_df(df, ~tibble(class = class(.), value = toString(unique(.))))

#  class   value  
#  <chr>   <chr>  
#1 numeric 1, 2, 3
#2 factor  a, b
```

---

Same in base R using `lapply`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(df, function(x) 
       data.frame(class = class(x), value = as.character(unique(x)))))
```

and

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(df, function(x) 
        data.frame(class = class(x), value = toString(unique(x)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

To address OP's comment asking about `enframe` and `unnest` I set up a benchmark.

[image]

```r
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(v1 = sample(1:100000,10000000, replace = TRUE), 
                 v2 = sample(c(letters,LETTERS),10000000, replace = TRUE))
library(tidyverse)

map(df, ~str_c(unique(.x),collapse = ",")) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  gather(key = col_name, value = col_unique)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   col_name col_unique                                                      
#>   <chr>    <chr>                                                           
#> 1 v1       51663,57870,2986,29925,95246,68293,62555,45404,65161,46435,9642~
#> 2 v2       S,V,k,t,z,K,f,J,n,R,W,h,M,P,q,g,C,U,a,d,Y,u,O,x,b,m,v,r,F,w,A,j~

map(df, ~str_c(unique(.x),collapse = ",")) %>% 
  enframe() %>% 
  unnest()
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   name  value                                                              
#>   <chr> <chr>                                                              
#> 1 v1    51663,57870,2986,29925,95246,68293,62555,45404,65161,46435,9642,59~
#> 2 v2    S,V,k,t,z,K,f,J,n,R,W,h,M,P,q,g,C,U,a,d,Y,u,O,x,b,m,v,r,F,w,A,j,c,~

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
bind_gather = map(df, ~str_c(unique(.x),collapse = ",")) %>% 
               bind_rows() %>% 
               gather(key = col_name, value = col_unique) ,
frame_unnest = map(df, ~str_c(unique(.x),collapse = ",")) %>% 
                enframe() %>% 
                unnest() ,
times = 10)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>   bind_gather 581.6403 594.6479 615.0841 612.9336 618.3057 697.6204    10
#>  frame_unnest 568.6620 590.0003 604.2774 606.5676 624.8159 630.2372    10
```

It seems that `enframe %>% unnest` is slightly faster than using `bind_rows %>% gather()`.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for doing this. I will have to look into it's uses more.

Comment: @alexb523 I've been using `unnest` for a while but tbh I just heard of `enframe` in this akrun's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57167112/6461462) and well I loved it so far.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

`data.table::rbindlist(list(map(df, class), map(df, function(x) list(unique(x)))))`

Comment: This is pretty close, but i need it to be a table with the column names tabulated and then a column for class and unique values. The end result is a data dictionary.